# RNN Cell not present in tf.get_collection

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

RNN Cells are not showing up when using `tf.get_collection()`. What am I missing?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(16)
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))

other_var = tf.Variable(0)
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))
```

prints out

```
0.12.0
[]
[<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x0000027961250B70>]
```

Windows 10, Python 3.5

Comment: You will need to `__call__` the `LSTMCell` to create its variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not run a `__call__` on the `LSTMCell` which is why you don't see your variables. Try this instead (I'm assuming `batch_size=10` and `rnn_size=16`)

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(16)
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, 16])
zero = rnn_cell.zero_state(10,tf.float32)
# The variables are created in the following __call__
b = rnn_cell(a, zero)
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))

other_var = tf.Variable(0)
print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))
```